# How to Observe LiveData and Transform between data models in Android Application

Tags: android, realm-mobile-platform, android-livedata

My current Android application is attempting to combine `LiveData` with `RealmIO`.

I have the basic functionality working as desired however I believe there are possible refactoring improvements.

I am attempting to isolate my Realm data model from the rest of the application.

My transformation code between Realm and UI data model is:-

```
 private final MutableLiveData<LocationUI> LOCATION_DETAILS = new MutableLiveData<>();
 ...
    public LiveData<LocationUI> getLocation(final String locationId) {

        final Realm LocationRealm = Realm.getInstance(REALM_CONFIGURATION.Location.getRealmConfiguration());
        final RealmQuery<Location> query = LocationRealm.where(Location.class);
        query.equalTo(LOCATION_ID, locationId);

        final Location location = query.findFirst();

        if (location == null) {


    return LOCATION_DETAILS;
    }

    final LiveRealmObject<Location> liveLocation = new LiveRealmObject<>(location);

    return Transformations.switchMap(liveLocation, input -> {
        final LocationUI locationUI = Location_MAPPER.mapLocation(input);
        LOCATION_DETAILS.setValue(locationUI);
        return LOCATION_DETAILS;
    });
}
```

Its this particular code that seems wrong

```
    return Transformations.switchMap(liveLocation, input -> {
        final LocationUI locationUI = Location_MAPPER.mapLocation(input);
        LOCATION_DETAILS.setValue(locationUI);
        return LOCATION_DETAILS;
    });
```

The fact that I am both setting the value of my MutableLiveData and returning it from Transformations.switchMap()
seems wrong.

How can I separate the Transformation from RealmIO to UI data model and the observing of the UI LiveData.